# Planar Investigator

Tags: logical-deduction, visual, number-sequence, graph-theory, primes

Use logical deduction to place a different digit from 1 to 9 in each circle below so that 8 of the arrows form the primes 23, 31, 41, 53, 59, 79, 89, and 97. (We view an arrow starting at digit A and ending at digit B as forming the 2-digit number AB.)

[image: A complex arrangement of circles and arrows between them.]

Then find a path traversing each arrow exactly once so that the first visit to a circle leaves by its southeast exit, and every subsequent visit leaves by its next exit, going clockwise. **What sequence of digits do you get?**

Bonus: Extend the sequence by adding the next arrow; inevitably, it will cross over other arrows. **Can you rearrange the circles and arrows so that once again no arrows cross?** (Pretend we're drawing points and curved lines in the plane—no [lateral-thinking](/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking).)

Hint:

> The colors are simultaneously a subtle verification of the first part, a not-so-subtle hint for the bonus, and an Easter egg.

Comment: You list just 8 two-digit primes, but there are a lot more than 8 arrows. Also, does an arrow go from the left (tens) digit to the right (units) digit?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis The condition only gives partial information, about 8 of the arrows. And yes, an arrow goes from the left (tens) digit to the right (units) digit. Thanks for asking, I've clarified these points in the question.

Comment: I got the order of the numbers ; I am not able to Proceed because "South East" looks a bit ambiguous. Eg 1 : The centre YELLOW node has East as well as South , hence not sure which comes first. Eg 2 : The centre BLUE has South, East and South East , hence not sure which comes first. I suggest you mark the "Starting Exit" in the Image.

Comment: @Prem Sorry for the confusion, and thanks for the suggestion, but I won't be able to get to it right away. I tried to make it clear by having one arrow start at exactly the southeast of each circle, including the two that you mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

The Numbers can be filled only in this order, top to bottom, left to right:

> BLUE 6, 3, 9 ; WHITE 1, 7, 4 ; YELLOW 2, 5, 8 ;

Pictorially:

> [image: BLUE 6, 3, 9 ; WHITE 1, 7, 4 ; YELLOW 2, 5, 8 ;]

Deductions:

> Lots of Possibilities/variations to consider, but basically it goes like this:
>  The numbers 79 & 97 give a loop;
>  9 must be the upper right corner BLUE node, because the other node can not form 89;
>  Now the bottom two YELLOW nodes must contain 5 & 8 to give 59 & 89.
>  These two Possibilities/variations give two variations to get 31 & 41.
>  23 eliminates one Possibility/variation.
>  We are left with the order listed.

Path:

> Consider the BLUE node at the upper right corner; It gives a substring (8|5)9793
>  Consider the YELLOW node at the lower left bottom; It gives a substring 265
>  Plugging these into [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=DIGITS%20265%2089793) gives [PI DIGITS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi) in the results (but user Penguino has already got that)
>  We can check that the Starting Point it 3 and we get 3.1415926535897932384

Extending:

> We can extend with more Pi DIGITS, the next being 6.
>  When connecting 4 & 6, it will intersect the other connections.
>  We can avoid that by enlarging the area within 1,3,4,8 and moving those to the outer area and putting all the others in the new inside area.
>  With this arrangement, we can connect 4 & 6 without intersecting the other connections.

Bonus:

> Puzzle was Posted around [PI DAY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_Day) which is great !

Comment: Do you mind adding a drawing of your solution for the bonus when you get the chance?

Comment: @noedne , I do not have the tools right now, but will try that in a little while.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers are as suggested by Prem. If you start at

> 3

and follow them in the order shown in the following diagram

> [image]

you get the first 20 digits of

> Pi (3.1415926535897932384)